# Why julia is very slow for the first evaluation?

Tags: julia

I am a newbie on Julia. Run the following code:

```
const size = 100
@time A = rand(size, size) * rand(size, size)
@time B = rand(size, size) * rand(size, size)
@time a = det(A)
@time b = det(B)

print(a, "\n", b)
```

Then I get something like this:

```
  0.825584 seconds (259.77 k allocations: 13.101 MiB)
  0.000248 seconds (11 allocations: 234.813 KiB)
  0.297366 seconds (44.59 k allocations: 2.591 MiB)
  0.012814 seconds (12 allocations: 79.375 KiB)
-9.712788203190892e49
-5.471097050756647e49
```

Why the first call of either matrix multiplication or evaluation of determinant is extremely slow? How to avoid this?

Comment: The first time it compiles the function. If you put this all in a larger funciton, it'll only compile once. When running anything of sizable length this doesn't really matter because the first call is just one of many. For package functions you can precompile them and store the precompiled versions.

Comment: X-ref: `@btime` in [BenchmarkTools.jl](https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't trust the outcome of timing with variables in global scope. Try to put it in a function and run it again. Also, the first time you run the function it will compile, so that will take some time.